# Eclipse GMF Compartment Node (List Layout) - Every Compartment Collapsed at start

Tags: eclipse, graph, emf

I created a gmf model using eugenia with the following node in it:

```
     @gmf.node(label="name", border.width="0", margin="1", label.icon="false")
     class ShElement {
        attr String name;
        ref EObject element;

        @gmf.compartment(layout="list")
        val ShElement[*] subelements;
      }
```

It works fine but sadly it is completely expanded when inserting it into the graph.

So i would like to know if there is a possibility to add the Node and have it and all Childs collapsed at the beginning?

Answer (score 1):

accordingly to [GMF Documentation](https://www.eclipse.org/epsilon/doc/eugenia/#gmfcompartment-for-containment-ereference) there is a collapsible variable that you can use to do so.

Comment: thanks for the answer. 
But i think this is only to allow the general collapsing of the compartment.
It would still be expanded when it is first shown.